# Can mixing too much citric acid and bicarbonate of soda create dangerous levels of carbon dioxide in the home?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am not a chemist. In order to clean hard limescale in my toilet, I usually put down half a cup of bicarbonate of soda and half a cup of citric acid.

Someone told me this is dangerous because it creates too much $\ce{CO2}$. Is this true?

Comment: No, it's *not*.

Comment: And it doesn't sound like a good way to clear limescale either.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and it cleans it off just fine.

Comment: Since it is about chemistry here: fine it cleans but the mixing does not make sense / It does create CO2 but  unless you do that on tub scale see Mithoron above.

Comment: Using both acid and bicarbonate does not make sense. Limestone and limescale is destroyed by citric acid or any other acid. Using citric acid is a good way of getting rid of this deposit. But adding bicarbonate is counter-productive. Because bicarbonate destroys citric acid (as any other acid). So adding bicarbonate to citric acid is similar to removing citric acid, and preventing it to dissolve limescale or limestone. It produces huge amounts of foam, but it does not clean your toilet.

Answer (score 2):

I have used citric acid in toilets lots of times, but never with sodium bicarbonate. At work, the incoming water (rusty pipes?) was so discolored that I would add a spoonful (not a half cup!) of citric acid and stir with a brush - the bowl sparkled.

At home, a spoonful of citric acid would clean off any grunge that had accumulated, but I admit I had no hard deposits.

If you assume a half cup of sodium bicarbonate is about $\pu{200 grams}$, and add enough citric acid to react completely with it, and it all comes out of solution, you could get $\pu{53 liters}$ of $\ce{CO2}$ gas, or about 14 gallons, which is indeed, quite a lot. In fact, unless you have some special technique, I would expect your toilet bowl to bubble over. Perhaps your cup is somewhat smaller than I imagine.

A normal concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ in air is about $\pu{400 parts per million (ppm)}$, but can get up to $\pu{1000 ppm}$ indoors, safely. The workplace limit (8 hour exposure) is $\pu{5000 ppm}$. Possible headaches at this level. Over $\pu{40,000 ppm}$, coma, death, or even worse, brain damage (See [What are safe levels of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ in rooms?](https://www.kane.co.uk/knowledge-centre/what-are-safe-levels-of-co-and-co2-in-rooms)). That's $4$% percent. The $\pu{14 gallons}$ of gas would occupy $\pu{1.87 cubic feet}$, so if your bathroom were larger than $\pu{46.8 cubic feet}$, even with the door closed, you could escape death - and you would probably feel a strong desire to get more air. Now even a small bathroom $(\pu{ 8 \times \, 8 \times \, 7 feet})$ would have almost 10 times the volume, so you would be below the workplace limit, and you could get away with only headaches or dizziness. With any kind of ventilation (open a window or turn on the vent), there should be no significant health issue. (I am still imagining $\pu{14 gallons}$ of foam rising in a toilet bowl.)

Nevertheless, I suggest you use the citric acid alone - well, not completely alone - help it with a brush and let the acidic solution remain in the bowl for some time ($\pu{10 - 15 minutes}$ if needed). The bubbling action of the bicarbonate is probably not much help (opportunity for an experiment!). Although $\ce{CO2}$ does dissolve limestone (stalagtites and stalagmites), the citric acid does better.

Comment: I think citric acid is limiting, and there is only about 1 mole of it, enough to produce about 1 mole of carbon dioxide if you consider the speciation diagram. So I think your estimate is too high by a factor of about two.